# Consume a mockAPI with Angular6 via Node w/o Express

Tags: node.js, angular, rest

So far I have been able to consume a mock API with Angular's HttpClient module itself. I am now attempting to build backend to feed the API through Node.js. This is because later I want to feed the app real data and save that in a database.

I'm having trouble figuring out how to use *Node's* http module however. I realize Express exists to wrap a lot of boilerplate, but I like to stay as much in the raw as possible when learning. I will learn Express later.

The mock API serves a JSON string from the website mockapi.io. As said before, my frontend REST api can get the data if calling the mock directly. But as it is now I am suffering a misunderstanding of Node's Http.ClientRequest and Http.ServerResponse objects.

So from back to front:

**Backend Script (Node):** app.js

```
const request = require('request');
const http = require('http');

//returns a stream
let s = request('https://5b82c6892fd7f2001417916a.mockapi.io/mock');

let data = ''

s.on('data', (chunk) => {
data += chunk;
});

JSON.stringify(data);

s.on('end', () => {
console.log('Got data');
});

server = http.createServer((req, res) => {

const headers = { 
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',     
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'OPTIONS, POST, GET',
    'Access-Control-Max-Age': 2592000, // 30 days
};

    res.writeHead(204, headers);    
    res.write(data);
    res.end();
});

server.listen(3500);
```

**Frontend REST API (Angular6)**: data.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs'

//
import { Transaction } from '../models/transaction.model';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})



export class DataService {
  //https://5b82c6892fd7f2001417916a.mockapi.io/mock
  //
  baseUrl: string = 'http://localhost:3500/';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getAllTransactions(): Observable<Transaction[]> {
    return this.http.get<Transaction[]>(this.baseUrl);

  }

}
```

**The Repo Service that calls the REST API (ng6)** : transaction-respository.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

//
import { DataService } from './data.service';
import { Transaction } from '../models/transaction.model';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TransactionRepositoryService {

  private transactions: Transaction[];

  constructor(private dataservice: DataService) {
    this.dataservice.getAllTransactions().subscribe(
      (data) => { this.transactions = data; console.log('Transactions Received') },
      (error) => console.log(error),
      () => console.log('Repo GET request ended'));
  }

  getAllTransactions(): Transaction[]{
    return this.transactions;
  }

}
```

**The nG Component that calls the repo service (ng6)**:transactions.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Transaction } from '../../models/transaction.model';
import { TransactionRepositoryService } from '../../services/transaction-repository.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-transactions',
  templateUrl: './transactions.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./transactions.component.css']
})

export class TransactionsComponent implements OnInit {

  private transactions: Transaction[];
  private sortParam: number = 0;


  constructor(private repo: TransactionRepositoryService) {
    this.transactions = this.repo.getAllTransactions();
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  get trans(): Transaction[] {
    return this.transactions;
  }


}
```

**That component's template (ng6)**:transactions.component.html

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>ID</td>
      <td>Date/Time</td>
      <td>Vendor</td>
      <td>Category</td>
      <td>Amount</td>
      <td>Options</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let t of trans">
      <td>
        {{t.id}}
      </td>
      <td>
        {{t.date}}
      </td>
      <td>
        {{t.vendor}}
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" placeholder="category here" />
      </td>
      <td>
        {{t.amt}}
      </td>
      <td>

      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**And the data model in question (ng6)**: transaction.model.ts

```
export class Transaction{
  constructor(
    public id: number,
    public date: Date,
    public vendor: string,
    public amt: number,
    public category?: string
  ){}


}
```

Much appreciated,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed `res.writeHead(204, headers`) to `res.writeHead(200,header)`;